# Which drivers should I install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display-driver, chipset

I have HP Compaq Elite 8200 Small Form Factor desktop PC with Windows 7 64-bit.

I can download drivers for my PC on HP website but cannot decide which one is appropriate one.
I know that there are different versions of the same driver, then I should choose the latest one.

There are multiple chipset and graphic drivers. Should I install all of them except for the old versions of the same driver?

[image]

Comment: @Moab I know and I disagree. Among the 'same' drivers, I install the newest only. But there are multiple different drivers per each category.

Comment: Depends on the hardware, example, HP may have sold that pc with different wireless cards, you need to know what hardware you have, or things like Intel chipsets, there may be several drivers you need to install. Or use HP support assistant to download the drivers you need for your specific system. http://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/hpsupportassistant/hpsupport.html

Comment: Richie086's answer is a good solution also.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to determine what drivers you need for ANY HP desktop system (such as yours) is to download a tool from HP called the SoftPaq Download Manager.  Here is a link

ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/HP_SDM_Setup.exe

After you install the app, it will need to download the softpaq database.   After that is done, there is an option to search for drivers for your target desktop.   A list of compatible drivers will display in SDM and you can download the right driver from there.   Otherwise, you will have to try to download and install each driver, which is a PITA.

Unfortunately I do not have a HP desktop available, or I would post detailed steps & screens of what you need to do.  Let me know if you hit any snags, I am very familiar with the application and could easily help you get past any hiccups if you tell me what issues you are having.

Comment: I just tried this but I don't think this software recommends only necessary drivers for me. For example, I don't have Blu-ray drive or SSD, but it recommends drivers for them.

Comment: Most likely a system to make sure that if you get any of those devices, they work right when you plug in, without having to wait a while for the computer to download and install them.